getSession Returns null in Next.js API Route When Trying to Post a Blog
I'm implementing sign-in through Next.js and using next-auth for authentication. On the frontend, I'm able to retrieve the session using useSession without any issues. However, when I try to access the session in my API route using getSession, it returns null.
I'm trying to post a blog to MongoDB Atlas, and I need the session to associate the blog with the logged-in user. Here's my API route code:
import { dbConnect } from "@/lib/db";
import Blog from "@/model/blog";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  await dbConnect();
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  console.log("Request body:", req.body);
  console.log("Session:", session);
  if (!session) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ message: "You must be logged in to post a blog." });
  }
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { title, content } = req.body;
      const newBlog = new Blog({
        title,
        content,
        author: session.user.id,
      });
      await newBlog.save();
      res.status(201).json({ message: "Blog post created successfully!" });
    } catch (error) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ message: "Server error, please try again later." });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
  }
}

In the code above, getSession is returning null, which results in the API returning a 401 status. The frontend session is working correctly, but the backend API isn't recognizing the session.
What could be causing getSession to return null in the API route, and how can I resolve this?
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

import { authOptions } from "./auth/[...nextauth]";

const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

I use getServerSession but it does not work for me your text
